# Express mongodb find query results empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I'm trying to do an API call to my express server to fetch employees that work in the same place based on the location ID. However, the API call returns just an empty array while it does work in the command-line interface.

Employee model

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
  var schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      first_name: String,
      last_name: String,
      address: {
        housenumber: Number,
        street: String,
        city: String,
        zip: Number,
        country: String
      },
      phone: Number,
      mobile: Number,
      email: String,
      enrollment_date: Date,
      staff_id: Number,
      location: { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'location' },
      department: String,
      function: String, 
      active: Boolean
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );

  schema.method("toJSON", function() {
    const { __v, _id, ...object } = this.toObject();
    object.id = _id;
    return object;
  });

  const Employee = mongoose.model("employee", schema);
  return Employee;
};
```

Employee routing for API

```
  router.get("/location/:location_id", employees.findAllByLocation);
```

Employee controller handling above call

```
exports.findAllByLocation = (req, res) => {
  Employee.find({ location: req.params.location_id })
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Employees."
      });
    });
};
```

Dummy database data to test on

[image: Dummy database data to test on]

Postman API call result

[image: Postman API call result]

However, trying to find the user with that location ID in the command line interface does work and gives the desired output.

[[image: Powershell output3]

So somehow it messes up and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. I did some research and found that it might have to do with the location being a reference as an ObjectId. So I tried wrapping the req.params.location_id to an ObjectId might fix it but that didn't work.

What's the best way to get this working?

Comment: What is app.use() for that router?

Comment: `app.use("/api/employees", router);`

The method kinda works tho, if I leave out the condition to find by location, it shows a list off all employees. It's just somehow that it doesnt properly process the location id.

Comment: @m1ch14l You have defined `location` to be an `ObjectId` at the schema level but clearly it is stored as `String` in the database (from the screenshot)? Try changing the database entry with `location` to correct `ObjectId` and then test it out.

Comment: @ambianBeing I feel stupid now, I changed it in the database and now it's working perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @m1ch14l Most welcome. It happens all the time to us devs 

Answer (score 1):

In order to use promise chain, you have to return something and then returned value will be passed chained “then()” as data. In your example you should

```
      return Employee.find({location:req.params.location_id})
```

Comment: The output is still just `[]`

Comment: can you console.log(req.params.location_id) in controller